# Find Admin of a spdocument library

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a document library which is not inherting the site permission (Custom permission is set).Now i want to find out who has administator permission to this library using C#.

I need to list out user id which i have admin rights.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a *List Administrator*. But you can get the users and groups with manage lists permissions though:

```
SPList list = // get your list
IEnumerable<SPPrincipal> admins = list.RoleAssignments.Cast<SPRoleAssignment>()
  .Where(ra =>
    ra.RoleDefinitionBindings.Cast<SPRoleDefinition>()
      .Any(r => (r.BasePermissions & SPBasePermissions.ManageLists) == SPBasePermissions.ManageLists))
  .Select(ra => ra.Member);
```

**Update:**

Permissions on a `SPFolder` can be checked via the corresponding `SPListItem`. This can be retrieved via the [`SPFolder.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.item.aspx) property. Since both, the `SPListItem` and the `SPList`, inherit from the `SPSecurableObject` the check for the `SPListItem` is the same as described above.

To distinguish `SPUser` from `SPGroup` simply check the type of `SPRoleAssigment.Member`:

```
IEnumerable<SPUser> adminUsers = admins.OfType<SPUser>();
```

Be aware that a `SPUser` object can represent an AD security group. This can be checked via the [`SPUser.IsDomainGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.isdomaingroup.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply,That helps a lot.If i want find out user have permission to SPFolder object then how it can be done.Also how to find out whether admins[] have SPUser object or SPGroup object. Thanks in Advance and time.